# How can I control time with jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I really couldn't do that so I need to learn how to do that

I want to control time with jquery or javascript doesn't matter which one it is.I want to explain my scenario is:

I have agency page and my all agency have modal and theese modal has `open-hours` and `closed-hours` if you check it out my example..

and if my `data-open-hour` for example is `09:00` but if time is `10:00` now then remove `09:00` option and make first `10:00` and if `data-closed-hours` is `20:00` and if time past `20:00` then make  disabled `Call Today`

```js
function agencyModal(modalTitle, modalWidth, modalHeight, openHours, closedHours) {
  console.log("Open: " + openHours + " Closed hours: " + closedHours);
  var html =
    '<div class="modal fade agencyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"><div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="width:' + modalWidth + ';height:' + modalHeight + '"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
  html = html + '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">' + modalTitle + "</h4></div>";
  html = html + '<div class="modal-body">';
  html = html + '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-6"><select class="when-call form-control"><option class="call-today">Call Today</option><option class="call-tomorrow">Call Tomorrow</option></select></div><div class="col-lg-6">';
  html = html + '<select class="hour-call form-control">'+getOptions(openHours, closedHours, true)+'</select></div></div>';
  html = html + '</div></div></div></div>';
  // check length and append if it is not added before
  !$(".agencyModal").length && $(document.body).append(html);
  $(".agencyModal").modal();
}


$(document).on("click", ".open-agency", function() {
  var openHours = $(this).data("open-hours");
  var closedHours = $(this).data("closed-hours");
  agencyModal("Test Title ", "70%", "500px", openHours, closedHours);
});

function callNow() {
  return '<option class="call-now">Call Now</option>';
}

function getOptions(open, close, now) {
  var options = now ? callNow() : '';
  console.log(open,close,now);
  // get open/close time as hours only
  var start = open.split(':')[0];
  var end = close.split(':')[0];
  // using +start will convert to a base 10 number - avoiding the problem that numbers with a leading zero are octal numbers
  // loop and add an option for each
  for (var h = +start; h <= +end; h++) {
    options += '<option>Call at '+h+':00</option>'
  }
  return options;
}

$(document).on("change", ".when-call", function(event) {
  // not the most efficient way, but you can always remove 'Call now', then add it back only if needed
  $(".hour-call .call-now").remove();
  if($('.call-today').is(':selected')) 
    $('.hour-call').prepend(callNow());
});
```

```css
.open-agency {
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ccc;
}

.open-agency:hover {
  background: #050505;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p class="open-agency" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".agencyModal" data-open-hours="09:00" data-closed-hours="22:00">See Agency</p>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I love this question's title ! I'm a bit disappointed by its actual content though...

Comment: What you're doing here is manipulating your HTML content based on time constraint variables.  Depending on the size of your application it might make sense to adopt the use of a more robust DOM manipulation library (a "templating" language) like React or Angular or even Handlebars.  Even using something like Meteor's Blaze would be better than manually manipulating the DOM through jQuery.  This is how we would solve this problem maybe 10 years ago... these new tools allow us to follow "declarative states" for our view layers, this will save you so much time in the future. It's worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change a bit in your code

```
  var dt = new Date();
  var time = dt.getHours()
  // loop and add an option for each
  for (var h = +start; h <= +end; h++) {
    if (time < h && now == true) {
      options += '<option>Call at ' + h + ':00</option>'
    } else if (!now) {
      options += '<option>Call at ' + h + ':00</option>'
    }
  }
```

This will now check the current Hour and remove any before that.

I've also changed this bit

```
  if ($('.call-today').is(':selected')) {
    $('.hour-call').prepend(getOptions(openHours, closedHours, true));
  } else {
    $('.hour-call').prepend(getOptions(openHours, closedHours, false))
  }
```

I will now reset the options when your change the select.

```js
var openHours;
var closedHours;

function agencyModal(modalTitle, modalWidth, modalHeight, openHours, closedHours) {
  console.log("Open: " + openHours + " Closed hours: " + closedHours);
  var html =
    '<div class="modal fade agencyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"><div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="width:' + modalWidth + ';height:' + modalHeight + '"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
  html = html + '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">' + modalTitle + "</h4></div>";
  html = html + '<div class="modal-body">';
  html = html + '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-6"><select class="when-call form-control"><option class="call-today">Call Today</option><option class="call-tomorrow">Call Tomorrow</option></select></div><div class="col-lg-6">';
  html = html + '<select class="hour-call form-control">' + getOptions(openHours, closedHours, true) + '</select></div></div>';
  html = html + '</div></div></div></div>';
  // check length and append if it is not added before
  !$(".agencyModal").length && $(document.body).append(html);
  $(".agencyModal").modal();
}


$(document).on("click", ".open-agency", function() {
  openHours = $(this).data("open-hours");
  closedHours = $(this).data("closed-hours");
  agencyModal("Test Title ", "70%", "500px", openHours, closedHours);
});

function callNow() {
  return '<option class="call-now">Call Now</option>';
}

function getOptions(open, close, now) {
  var options = now ? callNow() : '';
  console.log(open, close, now);
  // get open/close time as hours only
  var start = open.split(':')[0];
  var end = close.split(':')[0];
  // using +start will convert to a base 10 number - avoiding the problem that numbers with a leading zero are octal numbers
  var dt = new Date();
  var time = dt.getHours()
  // loop and add an option for each
  for (var h = +start; h <= +end; h++) {
    if (time < h && now == true) {
      options += '<option>Call at ' + h + ':00</option>'
    } else if (!now) {
      options += '<option>Call at ' + h + ':00</option>'
    }
  }
  return options;
}

$(document).on("change", ".when-call", function(event) {
  // not the most efficient way, but you can always remove 'Call now', then add it back only if needed
  $(".hour-call .call-now").remove();
  $('.hour-call option').remove();
  if ($('.call-today').is(':selected')) {
    $('.hour-call').prepend(getOptions(openHours, closedHours, true));
  } else {
    $('.hour-call').prepend(getOptions(openHours, closedHours, false))
  }
});
```

```css
.open-agency {
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ccc;
}

.open-agency:hover {
  background: #050505;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p class="open-agency" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".agencyModal" data-open-hours="09:00" data-closed-hours="22:00">See Agency</p>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you but time is 12:00 (Turkey) that is why option must start 13:00 is that possible?

Comment: @ani_css Try now

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to display only hours that are higher than the actual hour of the day, you need to test the iterated hour in your `getOptions()` function.

This is how should be the loop:

```
  for (var h = +start; h <= +end; h++) {
    var currHour = (new Date()).getHours();
    if(h>currHour)
        options += '<option>Call at '+h+':00</option>'
  }
```

**Demo:**

```js
function agencyModal(modalTitle, modalWidth, modalHeight, openHours, closedHours) {
  console.log("Open: " + openHours + " Closed hours: " + closedHours);
  var html =
    '<div class="modal fade agencyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"><div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="width:' + modalWidth + ';height:' + modalHeight + '"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
  html = html + '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">' + modalTitle + "</h4></div>";
  html = html + '<div class="modal-body">';
  html = html + '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-6"><select class="when-call form-control"><option class="call-today">Call Today</option><option class="call-tomorrow">Call Tomorrow</option></select></div><div class="col-lg-6">';
  html = html + '<select class="hour-call form-control">'+getOptions(openHours, closedHours, true)+'</select></div></div>';
  html = html + '</div></div></div></div>';
  // check length and append if it is not added before
  !$(".agencyModal").length && $(document.body).append(html);
  $(".agencyModal").modal();
}


$(document).on("click", ".open-agency", function() {
  var openHours = $(this).data("open-hours");
  var closedHours = $(this).data("closed-hours");
  agencyModal("Test Title ", "70%", "500px", openHours, closedHours);
});

function callNow() {
  return '<option class="call-now">Call Now</option>';
}

function getOptions(open, close, now) {
  var options = now ? callNow() : '';
  console.log(open,close,now);
  // get open/close time as hours only
  var start = open.split(':')[0];
  var end = close.split(':')[0];
  // using +start will convert to a base 10 number - avoiding the problem that numbers with a leading zero are octal numbers
  // loop and add an option for each
  for (var h = +start; h <= +end; h++) {
    var currHour = (new Date()).getHours();
    if(h>currHour)
        options += '<option>Call at '+h+':00</option>'
  }
  return options;
}

$(document).on("change", ".when-call", function(event) {
  // not the most efficient way, but you can always remove 'Call now', then add it back only if needed
  $(".hour-call .call-now").remove();
  if($('.call-today').is(':selected')) 
    $('.hour-call').prepend(callNow());
});
```

```css
.open-agency {
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ccc;
}

.open-agency:hover {
  background: #050505;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p class="open-agency" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".agencyModal" data-open-hours="09:00" data-closed-hours="22:00">See Agency</p>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes that's true but when I choose `Call Tomorrow` then select musn't be change only for `Call Today` is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the time from the `Date()` object like so:

```
//get current hours from the current Date object
var date = new Date();
var currentHour = date.getHours();
```

And then update your for loop to start only from `currentHour + 1`:

```
for (var h = currentHour; h <= end; h++) {
    options += '<option>Call at '+h+':00</option>'
}
```

For the 'Call Today' to be disabled you could check the date in the `agencyModal()` function and add the `disabled` keyword to the `<option>`.

```
'<option class="call-today"'+(new Date().getHours() > closedHours.split(':')[0] ? 'disabled': '' )+'>'
```

However, in order to change back to the full list of open hours when 'Call Tomorrow' is selected, you'd need an event listener for the first `<select>` and then apply the relevant changes from inside that function.

```js
function agencyModal(modalTitle, modalWidth, modalHeight, openHours, closedHours) {

  console.log("Open: " + openHours + " Closed hours: " + closedHours);
  
  var html =
    '<div class="modal fade agencyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"><div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="width:' + modalWidth + ';height:' + modalHeight + '"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
  html = html + '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">' + modalTitle + "</h4></div>";
  html = html + '<div class="modal-body">';
  html = html + '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-6"><select class="when-call form-control"><option class="call-today"'+(new Date().getHours() > closedHours.split(':')[0] ? 'disabled': '' )+'>Call Today</option><option class="call-tomorrow">Call Tomorrow</option></select></div><div class="col-lg-6">';
  html = html + '<select class="hour-call form-control">'+getOptions(openHours, closedHours, true)+'</select></div></div>';
  html = html + '</div></div></div></div>';
  // check length and append if it is not added before
  !$(".agencyModal").length && $(document.body).append(html);
  $(".agencyModal").modal();
}


$(document).on("click", ".open-agency", function() {
  var openHours = $(this).data("open-hours");
  var closedHours = $(this).data("closed-hours");
  agencyModal("Test Title ", "70%", "500px", openHours, closedHours);
});

function callNow() {
  return '<option class="call-now">Call Now</option>';
}

function getOptions(open, close, now) {
  var options = now ? callNow() : '';
  console.log(open,close,now);
  
  
  //get current hours from the current Date object
  var date = new Date();
  var currentHour = date.getHours();
  
  // get open/close time as hours only
  var start = open.split(':')[0];
  var end = close.split(':')[0];
  // using +start will convert to a base 10 number - avoiding the problem that numbers with a leading zero are octal numbers
  // loop and add an option for each
  for (var h = currentHour + 1; h <= end; h++) {
    options += '<option>Call at '+h+':00</option>'
  }
  return options;
}

$(document).on("change", ".when-call", function(event) {
  // not the most efficient way, but you can always remove 'Call now', then add it back only if needed
  $(".hour-call .call-now").remove();
  if($('.call-today').is(':selected')) 
    $('.hour-call').prepend(callNow());
});
```

```css
.open-agency {
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ccc;
}

.open-agency:hover {
  background: #050505;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p class="open-agency" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".agencyModal" data-open-hours="09:00" data-closed-hours="22:00">See Agency</p>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you but if `data-closed-hours` if past then make disabled `Call today` but its great :)

Comment: Edited the answer